# Percentiles for multiple columns

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table with around 200-250 columns and I want to compute the percentile for each of these columns.

Hive gives the Function, Percentile(int_exp,p) that returns the pth percentile value of the column int_exp. But it seems redundant to run the same query for rest of the 250 columns. Is there a way I can find the percentile of all columns at one go?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will have to call the percentile function for each column. One suggestion is that you could dynamically generate this query using some other language (e.g. Java, Ruby, Python, etc.)